# Who is the first user of this site?

Tags: support

Assuming userid is assigned incrementally, I found [this user](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/7/sorantiswho) has the lowest userid which is 7. But, what happened to lower userids? Are they deleted or for some unknown reason, the numbering started from 7?

Bonus: Who proposed the idea of this site in *Area 51*? When did this site come in existence (private beta, public beta, launch)?

Comment: The Community bot is user [_negative_ 1](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)

Comment: @Izkata - Didn't you mean user 65,535?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a user 1. The lowest user I can find is [Geoff Dalgas](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/2/geoff-dalgas), who was user #2. I believe he is a member of Stack Exchange. As for who proposed this site, look at the [Area 51 definition page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4451?phase=definition), and you can see it was jmfsg.

Comment: Can I get the dates of private beta, public beta and launch?

Comment: Look at area 51...

Comment: Unable to find dates there...

Comment: @SachinShekhar "beta" tab, upper-right of the page.

Comment: @Kevin "3 years ago" isn't date.

Comment: @SachinShekhar as with pretty much every other date on the site, hover your mouse over it.

Comment: @Kevin Oh sorry.. I am on mobile at this time. :)